# React state Toggle only works once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to toggle this one boolean value in the state of one of my components. This is how I'm doing it rn :

```
updateProduct(productID) {
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  content:{
    ...prevState.content
  },
  products:{
    ...prevState.products,
    [productID] : {  
      ...prevState.products[productID],
      editable : !prevState.editable
    }
  }
 }))
}
```

The problem is: This works, but only once i.e. It toggles the boolean from **false** to **true**, but then it gets stuck on being **true**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
editable: !prevState.products[productID].editable
```

Comment: I feel quite stupid now tbh, but thank you very much!